# CCS conditional passing when it shouldn't

Tags: c, circuit

Im working on a simple project making an elevator on proteus using CCS for the programming aspect, i have a display and a 4*3keypad and im using a pic16f877a, when going up there is message that says "subiendo..." (going up...), and when going down a message that says "bajando..." (going down...) and then show the floor you are currently on. The thing is that when i go down it shows the message of going up, but it does take me to the right floor, this is because it is somehow entering a if conditional when it shouldnt be entering it and i don't know why! please help.

```
#include <16F877A.h>
#use delay(clock=8M)
#fuses XT,HS,NOWDT,NOPUT,NOPROTECT,NOLVP

#define LCD_ENABLE_PIN PIN_B0
#define LCD_RS_PIN PIN_B1 
#define LCD_RW_PIN PIN_B2
#define LCD_DATA4 PIN_B4 
#define LCD_DATA5 PIN_B5 
#define LCD_DATA6 PIN_B6 
#define LCD_DATA7 PIN_B7
#define use_portb_kbd TRUE
#include <lcd.c>
#include <kbd.c>

int piso;
int x;


/// main program
void main()
{       

char destino;        


lcd_init();

kbd_init();
port_b_pullups(TRUE);

piso=1;  

lcd_putc("\f Piso 1");
while (true)            
{               
  if(input(PIN_A5)==0)
  {
     destino=kbd_getc();
     x=destino-48;

     if(destino!=0)
     {
     if(x==piso)
     {
     }
     if((x>piso)&&(x<7))
     {
        piso=x;
        lcd_putc("\f Subiendo...");
        output_high(PIN_D6);        
        delay_ms(1000);
        output_low(PIN_D6);           
        printf(lcd_putc,"\f Piso %d", piso);

     }

     if((x<piso)&&(x>0))
     {
        piso=x;
        lcd_putc("\f Subiendo...");
        output_high(PIN_D6);        
        delay_ms(1000);
        output_low(PIN_D6);           
        printf(lcd_putc,"\f Piso %d", piso);

     }
  }
  }
  else
  {
     lcd_putc("\f Limite de peso \n excedido");
     delay_ms(500);
     printf(lcd_putc,"\f Piso %d", piso);
     delay_ms(500);

  }

 }                    /// fin de bucle while
}
```

Comment: I see no "*"bajando..."*" in your code.

Comment: I am such a good damn idiot... To my defense it was 4 am when i posted this yesterday. Thanks a lot man tou, without this comment i wouldn't have notices how much of an idiot i am